# How to store keys for JSON dictionary using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to figure out a good way to store keys for JSON-based dictionary using Python 2.7. If I store them as strings like it is in the code below, using them later on looks very ugly. What is a better way to do it?

```
import requests
r = requests.get(urlSpecifiedAbove)
dict = r.json()
listKeys = [
"['main']['tabs']['geography']['columns']['overall_rate_performance']['title']",
"['main']['tabs']['geography']['columns']['overall_rate_performance']['revenue_vs_book_rate_revenue']"
]
myCode = 'neededValue = dict' + listKeys[0]
exec(myCode)
print neededValue
```

Comment: Why are you using Python 2? Why would you use `exec()`? Why are your variable names in the `camelCase` style? Can you explain further why you need to "store the keys"?

Comment: @AMC as strange as it might be, there's still a lot of py2 code out there that need to be maintained. And while it's not pep-08 compliant, camelCase variables are legal.

Comment: " store keys for JSON-based dictionary" => there's no such thing as a "JSON-based dictionnary". You either have json which is a text format (IOW a `str` or `unicode` object) or a plain Python `dict`, which is your case here. The fact that this dict was obtained as the result of parsing a json-formatted string is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Oh of course, there are plenty of cases where Python 2 and/or camelCase names are absolutely the right way to go, I just mention it since very few, if any, of those cases involve beginners to the language.

Comment: @AMC I don't know how long you've been in the business, but it's actually quite common to see beginners being assigned boring maintainance grunt work on technos they don't have a clue about :-/ (been here, done that etc)

Answer (score 1):

A path through nested dicts is a list of keys.

```
path = ['main', 'tabs', 'geography', 'columns', 'overall_rate_performance', 'title']
```

You can descend one key at a time through this list:

```
def get_value_at_path(root, path):
    for key in path:
        root = root[key]

    return root


root = r.json()
path = ['main', 'tabs', 'geography', 'columns', 'overall_rate_performance', 'title']
needed_value = get_value_at_path(root, path)
```